# SQL os registros de maior data de um atributo

Tags: mysql

Eu possuo uma tabela chamada `kanban_card_journals` que possui os seguintes atributos:

- id
- kanban_card_id
- issue_journal_id
- created_at

Onde os três primeiros são números e o último data e hora.
Essa tabela salva a data de todas as alterações de um `kanban card`. O meu problema é que eu preciso saber qual foi a última vez que um `kanban card` foi atualizado, isto é, a data da última atualização de um `kanban_card_id`.

Eu tentei o comando:

```
select distinct id, kanban_card_id, created_at from kanban_card_journals where kanban_card_journals.created_at = (select max(created_at) from kanban_card_journals);
```

Ele me retorna os dados do último registro atualizado, mas eu não sei como faz para trazer o último de cada cartão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está buscando a maior data geral, sem considerar cada kanban_card_id.

```
SELECT distinct id, kanban_card_id, created_at FROM kanban_card_journals GROUP BY kanban_card_id HAVING MAX(created_at);
```

Nessa query adicionei a cláusula `GROUP BY` e um `HAVING` no final. Desse modo o `SELECT` trará os registros com as maiores datas agrupando por `kanban_card_id`.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.
Eu nunca havia mexido com as cláusulas GROUP BY e HAVING.